# Most efficient way to get record from MAX(col2), grouped by col1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table such as the below:

```
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
|----|----|----|----|----|
|A   |1   |x   |y   |y   |
|A   |2   |x   |x   |y   |
|B   |1   |x   |y   |x   |
```

What I want to do is return a single record for a non-unique value in col1, based on the maximum value in col2.

I could do this with a self inner join such as:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM table a INNER JOIN (
                   SELECT col1, 
                          MAX(col2)
                     FROM table
                 GROUP BY col1) b 
       ON b.col1 = a.col1 AND b.col2 = a.col2
```

Which would return:

```
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
|----|----|----|----|----|
|A   |2   |x   |x   |y   |
|B   |1   |x   |y   |x   |
```

However, this seems inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: which database your using and what version?

Comment: Oracle, as per the tag. Version is 11g.

Comment: I couldn't understand why you removed the tag "sql". `oracle` stands for database, the spesific subject "sql" also needs to be added.

Comment: When you create a question with both `oracle` and `sql`, StackOverflow guidance says to only use one or the other, not both:
"SQL questions get better answers if they...
Include a tag for one specific database engine (MySQL, Oracle, etc...)
Show the SQL that isn't working
Describe exactly how it isn't working (error message, unexpected results, etc...)
Describe the desired results"

Comment: That guidance tells not to leave `sql` tag alone, add a DBMS tag also, since, mostly sql statement may contain properties spesific to a DBMS, that you already added, but `sql` tag is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can prefer using `in` operator with a more direct way

```
select *
  from "table"
 where (col1,col2) in ( select col1,max(col2)
                          from "table"
                         group by col1 
                          )
```

Answer (score 1):

use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
where col2 in (select max(col2) from tablename b where a.col1=b.col1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Oracle, do not need use correlated subquery or self-joins for this simple case. Just use analytic functions.

```
with s (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as (
select 'A', 1, 'x', 'y', 'y' from dual union all
select 'A', 2, 'x', 'x', 'y' from dual union all
select 'B', 1, 'x', 'y', 'x' from dual)
select*
from
 (select s.*, max(col2) over (partition by col1) mx
  from s
 )
where col2 = mx;

C       COL2 C C C         MX
- ---------- - - - ----------
A          2 x x y          2
B          1 x y x          1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

with s (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as (
select 'A', 1, 'x', 'y', 'y' from dual union all
select 'A', 2, 'x', 'x', 'y' from dual union all
select 'B', 1, 'x', 'y', 'x' from dual)
select*
from
 (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) rn
  from s
 )
where rn = 1;

C       COL2 C C C         RN
- ---------- - - - ----------
A          2 x x y          1
B          1 x y x          1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

with s (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as (
select 'A', 1, 'x', 'y', 'y' from dual union all
select 'A', 2, 'x', 'x', 'y' from dual union all
select 'B', 1, 'x', 'y', 'x' from dual)
select
col1,
max(col2) col2,
max(col3) keep (dense_rank last order by col2) col3,
max(col4) keep (dense_rank last order by col2) col4,
max(col5) keep (dense_rank last order by col2) col5
from s
group by col1;

C       COL2 C C C
- ---------- - - -
A          2 x x y
B          1 x y x

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```